# QTKit: determine if a QTMovie is paused?

Tags: macos, cocoa, qtkit

How can I tell, programmatically, if a `QTMovie` is playing or paused?

It seems like it would be simple, but I've combed through the [QTMovie](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/autoplay) and [QTMovieView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs rather extensively, and can find nothing of the sort.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for the movie's `rate`.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  rate is 0.0 when the movie is paused.  I wish the doc was more clear on that.  Thanks!